How to integrate different user types in djando UserModel?
I have a question regarding the user model in django. My project is to realize an area management system.
The following entities have already been modeled:

Building
Area
Area equipment (e.g. which furniture etc)
SpaceUser (assignment between space and user)
SpaceRequirement (request from a user)
Users (those who were, are and will be on the space)
Supervisor (user who is responsible for certain areas or buildings)
TypeOfUse (e.g. office, laboratory, etc.)
Organization (organizational affiliation to team/department etc)
Landlord

As a special case, the management of workshop spaces that are to be bookable at short notice is managed in the following entities:

WorkshopSpace (space x in building y)
WorkshopSpaceRequirement (request from a user)

The attributes of the entities are:
class Supervisor(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey('Organization', verbose_name='Organization', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class User(models.Model):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey('Organization', verbose_name='Organization', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mgmt_level = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=E4, verbose_name='Level')
    cost_center = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    number_employees = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Number of employees')
    number_workstations = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Number of workstations')
    superior = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)

Unfortunately, I made the mistake of implementing the models without taking the django user model into account. I would now like to correct this by using a CustomUser (inherits AbstractUser).
My current questions are:

Can I integrate the two entities user and supervisor with all their attributes in the CustomUser?
How does the subsequent user management in django work, for example, in the event that I create users as a superuser and these are only assigned to the real user at a later date?

Many thanks in advance!

Quick answer
Your first question
Yes, you'll be able to integrate all the fields for your two user types under the same User Model as long as you make any field that one type of user might have but not the other optional (you would also of course keep only one field for the fields that both user types do share).
You make fields optional by specifying null=True, blank=True;you need both, not just blank=True (null=True permits your database to store a null value for that field and blank=True allows your forms derived from that model to not require that field).
Your second question
Not exactly sure what you mean by "these [assuming you mean superusers by "these"] are only assigned to the real user at a later date", but I think you mean creating a relationship between two user models.
I would probably do this just by giving my CustomUser model (or profile model, more on that below) an "assigned user" ForeignKey field that connects right back to the CustomUser model (this StackOverflow question will tell you how to create a ForeignKey field to self).
A better way?
If I were to do this myself, instead of jamming all these fields into the same CustomUser model, I would

create a category field for my CustomUser model (using TextChoices or IntegerChoices) to designate which type of user any given CustomUser object is
then create two separate "profile" models (e.g., SupervisorProfile and UnderlingProfile) where all the fields you listed (and future fields you think of) would go.

I would put fields that both user types do not share in these separate profile models


link these profile models to the CustomUser model using optional ForeignKey fields

Why do I say this?
I essentially did something very similar to what you're wanting to do (all the same fields for unrelated user types on the same Model) on a big project of mine about a year ago and now I regret it. My models are less clean and less organized as a result.
